# Dependency of hardness in microstructure

Tags: material-science, metals

how does the hardness depend on copper and aluminum microstructure, Is it same like the steel microstructure or in the other way?

Answer (score 1):

The main mechanism is that the material is polycrystalline, meaning that it is composed of a large number of smaller crystals, of various orientations, joined by grain boundaries. Grain boundaries inhibit the motion of dislocations which thus makes the material harder. By contrast, it's carbon substitutions that inhibit dislocation motion in steel.